# JavaScript: file input onclick prevent change if user cancels confirm()

Tags: javascript, confirm, dom-events

How do I prevent a form file input element from changing via the onclick DOM event when using the confirm() method?

In example I want to give a user the opportunity to not lose the value of a file input element by asking them if they wish to Ok|cancel, if they click cancel the file dialog window should not be displayed.

**XHTML**

```
<input name="post_file" onclick="images_change();" type="file" value="" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function images_change()
{
 var answer = confirm('Okay or cancel, if you cancel no dialog window will be displayed.');

 if (answer)
 {
  answer = true;
  //previous item previews deleted here in a while loop.
 }
 else {answer = false;}

 return answer;
}
```

Comment: O.k. You are almost there, just return the `confirm` value, see my answer below.

Comment: @John If you need more from your answers than what you're currently asking -- "*[...] I need to execute some other scripting on top of that.*" -- you should edit your question to include this.

Comment: Colin, do not add unnecessary whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('post_file').addEventListener('click',function(e) {images_click(e);},false);

function images_click(e)
{
  var answer = confirm('Ok or cancel?');

  if (answer)
  {
   //shows file selection dialog window.
  }
  else {e.preventDefault();}
 }
}
```

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is soooo useful and cool. Thanks. I've wanted this previously but didn't find it in similar SO questions.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just inline it if you have the one file input?

HTML:

```
<input name="post_file" onclick="return check()" type="file" value="" />​
```

JavaScript:

```
function check() {
    return confirm('Okay or cancel, if you cancel no dialog window will be displayed.');
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bh97D/2/)**.

Comment: Why do you suggest him to use inline scripts?

Comment: Only the function can be called, inline scripting isn't something I can do though thanks for the answer.

Comment: If it's just a one off file input there's nothing wrong with it. If he needs to re-use it then I can see the point in separating it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `confirm` result, and return the function result:

```
<input name="post_file" onclick=" return images_change();" type="file" value="" />​

function images_change() {
    return confirm('Okay or cancel, if you cancel no dialog window will be displayed.');
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abq2L/)**

Comment: Basically the same as j08691.

Comment: That looks good though the problem is if the script returns true I need to execute some other scripting on top of that.