# Customize input type=file behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a file browser on my page using

```
<input type="file" />
```

Now on click of the browse button, I need to show a JS "confirm" popup.
Only on click of "OK" on that popup, I should show the file browser, else it should just cancel (not display the file browser/selector window)

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: file input onclick prevent change if user cancels confirm()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999585/javascript-file-input-onclick-prevent-change-if-user-cancels-confirm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[type="file"]').click(function(){
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to see me dance?");
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Qqqe/)

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

```
<input type="file" onclick="return confirm('Continue ?');"/>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H2bVP/)**</kbd>

Or make use of onclick event handler:

```
 $('input[type=file]').click(function(){
    return confirm("Continue ?");
 });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/p5Csc/1/)**</kbd>